# suggestions needed to define a class for field per entity/node

Tags: entities, theming

Im not sure the best way to go about this, and not so much a big programmer...

I would like to let the node creator decide whether the image in the image field should be top, left, or right. So i simply want to add class to the image div somehow.

So there should be a way to grab that info, maybe a "list" field?

Now, how to get that info over the image field?

Im thinking something like a field template for the image field (using media module)... or maybe something i heard about preprocessing in template.php?

pointer and tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Image Class](https://drupal.org/project/image_class) module - either use it directly, or use it's code - it is open source after all.

> Extends the Image formatter by adding an option to add an element class.

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice. However I'm using the media module, and also want something easy for the end user (radio select from preset)

Comment: @petergus well, Drupal is as much a framework as it is a CMS. As I have already said, "use it's code - it is open source after all" so you can tailor it to your specific needs.

Comment: :) ya, im not to much a programmer, but i had a look. I dont really want to use view modes, i just want to say 'hey, write the value of this field as a class to that field'. I will ask a new question to be more specific then. THanks!